# Unity Admob Integegration: Ads doent show anymore - but they used to?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a bit of a problem.
I used to monetize my apps via admob or appodeal. I had one app monetized via appodeal and another one with around the same traffic via admob. I realized that admob generates more cash, so i changed my project from appodeal to admob.
Even tho Im doing what is ask of me in the tutorials, and the debugger always states that a "dummy ad" is showing. My device will NOT display the ads. It will however do that on my other unity game.

All I am doing is this:

```
private InterstitialAd interstitial;

private void LoadInterstitial()
{
    MobileAds.Initialize(_appID);
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(_adUnitId);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    interstitial.LoadAd(request);
    if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
    {
        interstitial.Show();
    }
}
```

I have also noticed, that in my other project form earlier this year I didnt have to do the "MobileAds.Initizalize(_appID)" part. I didtn event need to provide an app id.

Can anyone help me? It used to work like a charm but now there is nothing!

THANKS :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solved my issue:
- there is a new version of the google api that you need to implement. the old one didn't work anymore. thats why it is asking you for an app id now.
don't worry though, your old apps still work.
also i had to disable "unityAds" from within the services menu on the right.
after that, the above code worked!